FlatList not scrolling on android - react native
I'm trying to create a custom drop down, on IOS its working fine, but on ANDROID can't scroll. Anyone worked with custom drop down before?
I followed every answer to fix this but nothing helped me. There is no drop down package can help me to use it instead of creating a custom one.
const CustomDropDown: React.FC<DropDownProps> = forwardRef(
  (
    { label, data, value, setValue, margin, placeholder },
    ref: ForwardedRef<TextInput>
  ) => {
    const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [show, setShow] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const { locale } = useContext(I18nContext);

    const openPicker = useCallback(() => {
      Keyboard.dismiss();
      setIsFocused(!isFocused);
      setShow(!show);
    }, [show]);

    const hidePicker = useCallback(
      (item: any) => {
        setIsFocused(false);
        setShow(false);
        setValue(item);
      },
      [show, value]
    );

    const getListItemStyles = useCallback(
      (item: string, index: number): any => {
        if (item === value) {
          if (index === 0) {
            return {
              borderTopRightRadius: 15,
              borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
              backgroundColor: colors.darkBlue,
            };
          } else if (index === data?.length - 1) {
            return {
              borderBottomRightRadius: 15,
              borderBottomLeftRadius: 15,
              backgroundColor: colors.darkBlue,
            };
          } else {
            return {
              backgroundColor: colors.darkBlue,
            };
          }
        }
        return {}; // Return an empty object if no special styles are needed
      },
      [value]
    );

    const ListItem: React.FC<ListItemProps> = memo(
      ({ item, index, value, hidePicker, getListItemStyles }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => hidePicker(item)}
          style={[styles.listItem, getListItemStyles(item, index)]}
        >
          <TextResponsive
            style={[
              styles.listItemText,
              item === value && { color: colors.white },
            ]}
          >
            {item}
          </TextResponsive>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    );

    const renderItem = useCallback(
      ({ item, index }: { item: string; index: number }) => (
        <ListItem
          item={item}
          index={index}
          value={value}
          hidePicker={hidePicker}
          getListItemStyles={getListItemStyles}
        />
      ),
      [value, hidePicker, getListItemStyles]
    );

    return (
      <View
        style={[{ flex: 1 }, margin && { marginLeft: 10 }]}
        className="mb-4"
      >
        <TextResponsive style={[styles.label, { fontFamily: fonts.bold }]}>
          {label}
        </TextResponsive>

        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPress={openPicker}
          disabled={data?.length === 0}
        >
          <View style={[styles.inputWrapper, isFocused && styles.inputFocused]}>
            <TextInput
              style={[
                styles.input,
                isFocused && { color: colors.darkBlue },
                { textAlign: locale.includes("ar") ? "right" : "left" },
              ]}
              value={value}
              placeholderTextColor={colors.grey}
              onFocus={() => setIsFocused(true)}
              onBlur={() => setIsFocused(false)}
              editable={false}
              placeholder={placeholder}
            />
            <View style={styles.icon}>
              <AntDesign
                name="caretdown"
                size={12}
                color={isFocused ? colors.darkBlue : colors.grey}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

        {show && (
          <View style={styles.listContainer}>
            <FlatList
              style={styles.list}
              data={data}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item}
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
);

export default CustomDropDown;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputWrapper: {
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: colors.grey,
    borderRadius: 7,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
  input: {
    paddingVertical: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    color: colors.grey,
  },
  inputFocused: {
    borderColor: colors.darkBlue,
    elevation: 1,
    shadowColor: colors.lightGrey,
    shadowOpacity: 10,
    shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 1 },
    overflow: Platform.OS === "android" ? "hidden" : "visible",
  },
  label: {
    marginBottom: 5,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  list: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    elevation: 5,
    zIndex: 220,
    width: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    borderRadius: 15,
    marginTop: 10,
    height: 200,
  },
  listItem: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  listItemText: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  icon: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: 10,
    top: 20,
  },
  listContainer: {},
});


I tried to addcontentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }} but didn't solve the problem

try getting the dimensions and adding removeClippedSubviews={false}
renderToHardwareTextureAndroid
contentContainerStyle={{width, height}} to your flatlist

@JulesUK didn't work

I fixed it by doing this, without using any package
import {
  FlatList,
  Keyboard,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View,
  Modal,
} from "react-native";
import React, {
  ForwardedRef,
  forwardRef,
  useCallback,
  useContext,
  useState,
  memo,
  useRef,
} from "react";
import { colors, fonts } from "@/reusableTools/css/css";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import TextResponsive from "./TextResponsive";
import { I18nContext } from "@/Context/I18nContext";

interface DropDownProps {
  label: string;
  data: string[];
  value: string;
  setValue: (text: string) => void;
  margin?: boolean;
  placeholder?: string;
}

interface ListItemProps {
  item: string;
  index: number;
  value: string;
  hidePicker: (item: string) => void;
  getListItemStyles: (item: string, index: number) => any;
}

const CustomDropDown: React.FC<DropDownProps> = forwardRef(
  (
    { label, data, value, setValue, margin, placeholder },
    ref: ForwardedRef<TextInput>
  ) => {
    const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const { locale } = useContext(I18nContext);

    const DropdownButton = useRef<any>();

    const [dropdownTop, setDropdownTop] = useState(0);

    const [dropdownWidth, setDropdownWidth] = useState(0);

    const [dropdownLeft, setDropdownLeft] = useState(0);

    const openPicker = useCallback(() => {
      visible ? setVisible(false) : openDropdown();

      Keyboard.dismiss();

      setIsFocused(!isFocused);
    }, [visible]);

    const hidePicker = useCallback(
      (item: any) => {
        setVisible(false);

        setIsFocused(false);

        setValue(item);
      },
      [value, visible]
    );

    const getListItemStyles = useCallback(
      (item: string, index: number): any => {
        if (item === value) {
          if (index === 0) {
            return {
              borderTopRightRadius: 15,
              borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
              backgroundColor: colors.darkBlue,
            };
          } else if (index === data?.length - 1) {
            return {
              borderBottomRightRadius: 15,
              borderBottomLeftRadius: 15,
              backgroundColor: colors.darkBlue,
            };
          } else {
            return {
              backgroundColor: colors.darkBlue,
            };
          }
        }
        return {}; // Return an empty object if no special styles are needed
      },
      [value]
    );

    const ListItem: React.FC<ListItemProps> = memo(
      ({ item, index, value, hidePicker, getListItemStyles }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => hidePicker(item)}
          style={[styles.listItem, getListItemStyles(item, index)]}
        >
          <TextResponsive
            style={[
              styles.listItemText,
              item === value && { color: colors.white },
            ]}
          >
            {item}
          </TextResponsive>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    );

    const renderItem = useCallback(
      ({ item, index }: { item: string; index: number }) => (
        <ListItem
          item={item}
          index={index}
          value={value}
          hidePicker={hidePicker}
          getListItemStyles={getListItemStyles}
        />
      ),
      [value, hidePicker, getListItemStyles]
    );

    const openDropdown = (): void => {
      DropdownButton.current.measure(
        (_fx: any, _fy: any, _w: any, h: any, _px: any, py: any) => {
          setDropdownTop(py + 4);
          setDropdownWidth(_w);
          setDropdownLeft(_px);
        }
      );
      setVisible(true);
    };

    return (
      <View
        style={[{ flex: 1 }, margin && { marginLeft: 10 }]}
        className="mb-4"
      >
        <TextResponsive style={[styles.label, { fontFamily: fonts.bold }]}>
          {label}
        </TextResponsive>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={openPicker} disabled={data?.length === 0}>
          <View
            style={[styles.inputWrapper, isFocused && styles.inputFocused]}
            ref={DropdownButton}
          >
            <TextInput
              style={[
                styles.input,
                isFocused && { color: colors.darkBlue },
                { textAlign: locale.includes("ar") ? "right" : "left" },
              ]}
              value={value}
              placeholderTextColor={colors.grey}
              onFocus={() => setIsFocused(true)}
              onBlur={() => setIsFocused(false)}
              editable={false}
              placeholder={placeholder}
            />
            <View style={styles.icon}>
              <AntDesign
                name="caretdown"
                size={12}
                color={isFocused ? colors.darkBlue : colors.grey}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <Modal visible={visible} transparent animationType="fade">
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.overlay}
            onPress={() => {
              setVisible(false);

              setIsFocused(false);
            }}
          >
            <View
              style={[
                {
                  top:
                    Platform.OS === "android" ? dropdownTop : dropdownTop + 40,
                  left: dropdownLeft,
                  width: dropdownWidth,
                },
                Platform.OS === "ios" && styles.iosShadow,
              ]}
            >
              <FlatList
                style={styles.list}
                data={data}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
);

export default CustomDropDown;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputWrapper: {
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: colors.grey,
    borderRadius: 7,
    marginTop: 5,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  input: {
    color: colors.grey,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    marginVertical: 15,
  },
  inputFocused: {
    borderColor: colors.darkBlue,
    elevation: 1,
    shadowColor: colors.lightGrey,
    shadowOpacity: 10,
    shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 1 },
    overflow: Platform.OS === "android" ? "hidden" : "visible",
  },
  label: {
    marginBottom: 5,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  list: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    elevation: 5,
    borderRadius: 15,
    marginTop: 10,
    height: 200,
  },
  listItem: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  listItemText: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  icon: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: 10,
  },
  overlay: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  iosShadow: {
    shadowColor: "#393b3a",
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 1 },
    overflow: Platform.OS === "android" ? "hidden" : "visible",
  },
});

